# In bigquery sql are curly braces allowed as part of a column alias

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to do something like this

```
SELECT epi_week {week}, state
FROM 
     lookerdata:cdc.project_tycho_reports
LIMIT 10
```

Error: Encountered " "{" "{ "" at line 1, column 17. Was expecting: EOF>

It seems that curly braces are not legal syntax. I've tried escaping or using quotes without success.

Is there a way around this? We use the braces as an indication for post-processing string replacement to support multiple languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way around this?

No way unfortunatelly. 
Field name must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 characters long.
As an option - you might want to come up with another name convention for post-processing

Comment: FYI, you *can* quote these identifiers in the query text using brackets (`[{week}]`), but the query will still fail when the results are written to a BQ table because of the field name constraints you mention.